# What is the purpose of creating a private heap

Tags: windows, process, operating-system

One can use the HeapCreate function to allocate a private heap from the calling process on Windows platform. While each process has its own default heap.

My question is: What are some possible reasons that a programmer use a private heap than the default one? In other words, in what scenario, using a private heap will become really handy?

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole long list of reasons for creating multiple heaps:

- Better efficiency with threads (threads do not share heaps).
- Debugging and error trapping
- Setting up heaps with different allocation properties.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Especially of the first point, that is how private heap makes multi-threads more efficient?

Comment: If each thread has its own heap, they do not have to lock the heap before allocating and deallocating.